# Azure AD Extension Property + MS Graph API PATCH = Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've been breaking my head over this problem for the past 2 days.

My goal is to allow a user (any regular non-admin Azure AD user) to update the value of an (Azure AD) extension property for his AD 'profile'/account through the Microsoft Graph API.

Consider the following situation:

- I'm in control (Global Admin) of some Azure tenant + Azure AD Directory
- There's a regular Azure AD User "Joe"
- I've created an App registration + Service Principal (either through PS or in the Azure Web UI)
- I've created an Azure AD Extension Property using the following Azure AD PS commands:

---

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId xxx-xxx-xxx
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId yyy-yyy-yyy
$app | New-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty -Name "MyProp" -DataType "String" -TargetObjects "User"
```

Response:

```
Name                                                  TargetObjects
----                                                  -------------
extension_b63fa5d85b9d43b8b60f982e4bf2ad11_MyProp     {User}
```

---

- I've Admin consented everything on Graph both on Enterprise Application "Graph Explorer" and on my own App Registration, especially *Directory.ReadWriteAll* and *User.ReadWrite.All*
- I then use the Graph Explorer (or Postman using my own App Registration) logged on as regular user "Joe"
- Using the following PATCH request fails:

---

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/

with body (type application/JSON):

{
    "extension_b63fa5d85b9d43b8b60f982e4bf2ad11_MyProp": "test"
}
```

It fails with the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d0ef63c0-f944-44c4-b90d-413b076b2bca",
            "date": "2019-04-11T08:21:48"
        }
    }
}
```

I seem to be unable to find out why this happens.
Things to note:

- When I log on in Graph Explorer as global admin I am able to update this property successfully
- I am also able to update this property for any user using Azure AD PS, logged in as global admin
- As soon as I give Joe the Global Admin or User Admin role in Azure AD he is able to update the property too
- As "Joe", using the above PATCH request in Graph Explorer (or Postman), I am able to update "mobilephone"
- As "Joe", using the above PATCH request in Graph Explorer (or Postman), I am **unable** to update "city", or "givenname"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you list the extensions in the directory? Can you add the output from `/v1.0/schemaExtensions` to your question?

Comment: Marc, this doesn't contain my custom extension property, it only shows all the "Available" extensions.
In my understanding, this is expected behavior and my Azure AD Extension Property shouldn't really appear here. Only Graph Extensions show up here. I've been experimenting with those as well but I can't create an Azure AD Group with dynamic users based on a Graph Extension, only AD Extension properties.

Comment: You should still be able to see the extension by filtering `/schemaExtensions` by it's `id`. I suspect the root issue here stems from creating the extension with PowerShell (making PS the owner) and then attempting to access it via Graph Explorer while it's still `InDevelopment`.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Marc.
I don't think I fully understand the extension concept(s). I thought that AD extension properties and Graph schema extensions aren't the same thing.
They're created using different procedures and their 'shape' is different too:
Azure AD extension props are formatted using "extension_[App Guid]_PropName" as a name. 
Graph schema extensions on the other hand have a 'schema-id' with format "[Domain]_[SchemaName]". The props that are part of this schema don't have any formatting restrictions.
What schema id would I even use to find my Azure AD Extension Props?